# SQL Error message:

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can anyone help me to find out what I'm doing wrong?

I am getting this error message when i press submit on the form:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2013-12-10', '', 'dsffsd', 'dfsfsd', 'sfdd', 'sdffsd', 'sdfsdf', 'sfdsdf', 'dsad' at line 8

and this is the php code at line 8:

```
function renderForm($caseref, $casetype, $clienttitle, $clientforename, $clientsurname, 
 $clientdob, $clienttelhome, $clienttelwork, $clienttelmob, $clientemail, 
 $clientaddress1, $clientaddress2, $clientaddress3, $clientaddress4, $clientaddress5, 
 $clientpostcode, $clientoccupation, $clientni, $defendanttitle, $defendantforename, 
 $defendantsurname, $defendantaddress1, $defendantaddress2, $defendantaddress3, 
 $defendantaddress4, $defendantaddress5, $defendantpostcode, $defendantvehiclereg, 
 $defendantpolicyno, $defendantinsurername, $defendantcomments, $softtissue, $boneinjury, 
 $whiplash, $injurydescription, $timeoffwork, $medicalattention, $attendedhospital, 
 $hospitalname, $hospitaladdress1, $hospitaladdress2, $hospitaladdress3, 
 $hospitaladdress4, $hospitaladdress5, $hospitalpostcode, $claimantposition, 
 $passengernumber, $claimantseatbelt, $ownertitle, $ownerforename, $ownersurname, 
 $owneraddress1, $owneraddress2, $owneraddress3, $owneraddress4, $owneraddress5, 
 $ownerpostcode, $drivertitle, $driverforename, $driversurname, $driveraddress1, 
 $driveraddress2, $driveraddress3, $driveraddress4, $driveraddress5, $driverpostcode, 
 $clientvehiclemake, $clientvehiclemodel, $clientvehiclereg, $clientinsurername, 
 $clientpolicyno, $doa, $timeaccident, $accidentlocation, $weatherconditions, 
 $roadconditions, $accidentcircumstances, $policereported, $namepolice, $incidentref, 
 $otherinfo, $submitdate, $error)
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO clients (caseref, casetype, clienttitle, clientforename, clientsurname, 
submitdate, clientdob, clienttelhome) VALUES ('$caseref', '$casetype', '$clienttitle', 
'$clientforename', '$clientsurname', '$submitdate', '$clientdob', '$clienttelhome')
```

Comment: Thanks for telling us. If you have a question please come back and ask.

Comment: Since this is an SQL error, it might be helpful if you showed the query and how it was created.

Comment: The error that you're getting is from a generated SQL query, not your PHP code. If you could add the query, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to guess without as much details as needed, but i think you are escaping the values with aphostropes (`'`). That's php's habit. MySQL doesn't escape those values with aphostropes, it uses backtiks (`) or nothing. You could change your query part which you provided to remove those symbols:

...

```
2013-12-10, NULL, dsffsd, dfsfsd, sfdd, sdffsd, sdfsdf, sfdsdf, dsad
```

...

Edit:

You have writed space between values and (). No space needed. Change it like this:

```
INSERT INTO clients (caseref, casetype, clienttitle, clientforename, clientsurname, 
submitdate, clientdob, clienttelhome) VALUES('$caseref', '$casetype', '$clienttitle', 
'$clientforename', '$clientsurname', '$submitdate', '$clientdob', '$clienttelhome')
```

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO clients (caseref, casetype, clienttitle, clientforename, clientsurname, submitdate, clientdob, clienttelhome) 
VALUES ('$caseref', '$casetype', '$clienttitle', '$clientforename', '$clientsurname', '$submitdate', '$clientdob', '$clienttelhome')")
or die(mysql_error());       ||| THIS IS THE MYSQL_Query code |||